# Сценарий в php для бота ВК

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, бот

я делаю бота для ВК, 
и вот как сделать допустим такой сценарий:

Бот: Укажите сумму пополнения:
Юзер: 1000

И в это время уже бот начинает работу с данным числом.
Я не пойму , как дать боту понять, что сейчас нужно ждать, пока конкретный юзер укажет число, каким образом это сделать?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, которым вы пытаетесь все это дело запустить.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать регулярки, либо же

```
if(is_numeric($body)) {
    // ... здесь уже выполняем нужный код если пользователь прислал число
}
```

Comment: Это конечно круто, НО , если случайно кто то напишет просто цифры, то бот начнет пополнение... А это так себе вариант. НУжно чтобы это все нацелено было